# How to store a non-standard persistent attribute in Core Data (ex. NSRect)?

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, core-data

I'm struggling with my first Core Data app and not having the smoothest ride :o(

I have a drawing app with a baseclass called DrawingObject which subclasses NSManagedObject and has two properties:

```
@NSManaged var frameAsValue: NSValue
var frame: NSRect
```

DrawingObject has a subclass DrawingRectangle. All have corresponding entities with fully qualified classnames set. The frameAsValue attribute is marked as transformable and frame is marked as Undefined transient. The problem is that I get an unrecognised selector error for the frameAsValue property when creating a DrawingRectangle.

I've seen suggestions to transform NSRect to a string to save it to Core Data but this seems error prone (localization) and hackish (if thats a proper word ;o). Here is the code for DrawingObject:

```
class DrawingObject: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var frameAsValue: NSValue

    var frame: NSRect = NSZeroRect {
        didSet {
            frameAsValue = NSValue(rect: frame)
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromInsert() {
        frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 0, 0)
    }

    override func awakeFromFetch() {
        frame = frameAsValue.rectValue
    }
}
```

I'm now assuming that you have to declare all of the inherited properties in the class hierarchy in each entity. I don't have time to test this now, but will be back soon.

Comment: NSRect is not a supported type in the Core Data model inspector. How did you define the Core Data property?

Comment: Using transformable as I assumed it was NSCoding compliant

Comment: You could transform the NSRect to a string and store that instead: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html

Comment: I don't think so (NSRect is a C struct, not a class). Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html, there are examples specifically for NSRect.

Comment: Your problem seems to be unrelated to *subclasses* (and in that case you should update the title and the contents accordingly).

Comment: I'll update the title as soon as I'm sure the problem is not related to subclassing. Why would I get a unrecognised selector error when I know the superclass has that attribute even if it can't yet be saved to Core Data because NSRect doesn't get automatically transformed by a KeyedArchiver.

Comment: @SeppoSilaste: Properties marked with `@NSManaged` are created dynamically at runtime only (similar to `dynamic` in Objective-C). That fails in your case.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for your input. I've updated my question and am now facing the same "unrecognised selector error" for the entityFrame property which is a NSValue and certainly NSCoding compliant. Where is the elephant hidden? As I wrote in the question, I think it could be nice to have a working implementation of saving a NSRect to Core Data since at least I haven't found one anywhere---only handwaving descriptions of it.

Comment: @MartinR The problem seems to be related to subclassing after all as I can save and retrieve a NSValue backed rect if I put the persistent property in the NSManagedObject class that represents the entity. So what I'm asking myself is: when I create a DrawingRectangle how do the superclass entities get mapped? In other words the superclass properties never get dynamically created irrespective of their type (I tried adding a string-property to the parent class and this also resulted in a unrecognized selector error)

Comment: @MartinR I'm now working on the assumption that each entity that is mapped to some subclass of a custom NSManagedObject, has to declare all the properties that are inherited from the superclasses in the class hierarchy. This means that the DrawingRectangle-entity would have to have also frame and frameAsValue as its properties even though they are inherited in the class hierarchy. I don't have time to test this today, so I will have to tinker on tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set parent entity of DrawingRectangle to DrawingObject to be able to inherit the properties from the parent entity (just like in the class-hierarchy). You also have to set parent--child entity relationships if you intend to save different subclasses of a parent-entity/parent-class into the same to-many relationship.

For examble if you want to save different subclasses of DrawingObjects in a `@NSManaged var objects: NSSet` in a Drawing for example, you have to set the parent relationships on the entities to correspond to your NSManagedObject class-hierarchy. So in this case you would set the parent of the DrawingRectangle entity to DrawingObject.

Otherwise NSRect is saved as in the code shown in the question by setting the frame-property of the DrawingObject-entity to transient and optional and the frameAsValue as transformable. You should not specify a valuetransformer so Core Data will use the default value transformer which works perfectly in this case.